# NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, networking, asynchronous, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I just found out about [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) at official docs

and was wondering if the emulator is throwing this. I have been testing my app quite a bit and as far as I know all networking is off the main thread (using Roboguice RoboAsyncTask) but you never know if one has not escaped.

I am also using StrictMode and have not seen anything.

1. Is my code just clean or is this not thrown on the emulator?
2. How are we supposed to prepare for this happening in production?
3. What about a grace period or something? 
   Or is that elapsed now ;-) ??

Comment: This was introduced in Android 3.0. I got it when i was doing a network operation on the UI thread, as the documentation states. I moved and run the operation on a separate thread and it was gone.

Comment: You get it in the emulator too or just with a device? Without StrictMode enabled?

Comment: I got it on the emulator without running in StrictMode.

Comment: It should not be hard to intentionally cause this if you want to be sure that it's going to result in an error message.

Comment: @Samuh may i ask which version of android emulator u were using when u get NetworkOnMainThreadException? cause I could not reproduce this erro on the emulator at all. Thanks!

Comment: Read this [blog post on the **`NetworkOnMainThreadException`**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html) for more information... it's very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tested this and it does in fact happen on the emulator as well. Better make sure you test your app at least on the emulator if you plan to get it onto the 3.0 tablets and beyond.

Comment: The docs say this:
"This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness."

Comment: **[Read my blog post on the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` for more information.](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)** It explains why this occurs on Android 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 13):

With honeycomb you can not perform a networking operation on its main thread as documentation says. For this reason you must use handler or asynctask. There is no another way to do it.

here you can find 2 examples written in turkish about networking operation. maybe they help.

- [3. party kütüphane kullanmadan (ksoap2)](http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/3-party-kutuphane-kullanmadan-ksoap2.html), (it includes english translation)
- [AsyncTask class'tan dönen parametreyi handle etmek.](http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/asynctask-classtan-donen-parametreyi.html) , [google translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/asynctask-classtan-donen-parametreyi.html&act=url)

Comment: Using `Handler` doesn't necessarily solve the problem. The default behaviour of `Handler` also executes on the main (UI) thread.

Answer (score 2):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs when some networking operations are performed inside main method; I mean `Oncreate()`. You can use `AsyncTask` for resolving this issue. or you can use

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy mypolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

inside `onCreate()` method.

Comment: This is wrong. The exception is thrown when performing Network I/O on the **main Thread**. This can happen in any method, not just in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on 3.0, i can't help; Because Strict mode is on by default in it; But its above tat, then this might help

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Include this before your HTTP connection creation; Then it works

Comment: old answer, but please be assured: It is the wrong way to do! Do never ever any network stuff on the UI thread. A kitten will die for every millisecond of delay you cause with that...

Answer (score 1):

From Honeycomb SDK (3), Google will no longer allow network requests (HTTP, Socket) and other related operations directly in the Main Thread class, in fact, should not do direct network operation in the UI thread, blocking UI, user experience is bad! Even if Google is not prohibited, under normal circumstances, we will not do it ~!
So, that is, in the Honeycomb SDK (3) version, you can also continue to do so in Main Thread, more than 3, it will not work.

**1.use `Handler`**

The more time-consuming operations associated with network are placed into a child thread and then communicated with the main thread using the `Handler` messaging mechanism

```
public static final String TAG = "NetWorkException";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_net_work_exception);
    // Opens a child thread, performs network operations, waits for a return result, and uses handler to notify UI
    new Thread(networkTask).start();
}

Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        // get data from msg and notify UI
        Bundle data = msg.getData();
        String val = data.getString("data");
        Log.i(TAG, "the result-->" + val);
    }
};

/**
 * net work task
 */
Runnable networkTask = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do here, the HTTP request. network requests related operations
        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("data", "request");
        msg.setData(data);
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

**2.use `AsyncTask`**

```
public static final String TAG = "NetWorkException";
private ImageView mImageView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_net_work_exception);
    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    new DownImage(mImageView).execute();
}


class DownImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    private ImageView imageView;

    public DownImage(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            //load image from internet , http request here
            InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // nodify UI here
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**3.use `StrictMode`**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```