# connecting android app with web server

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile, networkonmainthread

my connection code is this to get string from website....

url value is http://sagindia.netne.net/sendmail.php

```
public String makeServiceCall(String url) {
    try {
      // http client
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
      HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
      httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
      httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
      response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
   } catch (Exception e) {

   }
   return response;
}
```

showing error in line

```
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

log cat error part..

```
03-08 15:46:06.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1004): Caused by: anroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

i have rtied to solve this problem , but couldn't solve this...i am first time trying to get response from server....if anybody have solution plz help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: you need to doing Network related work in Background using AsyncTask

Comment: @SimplePlan yes sir...is Background using AsyncTask is required or are you saying this is reson of error..i can't get you

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary Both

Comment: @BlackTiger i have got my answer from your given link...thanks alot..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer from provided link by @blackTigher ...

problem was because of network on main thread...

so added this code before the connecting to httpclient

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

It worked for me...

for more detail can visit at [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception)