# App crash when trying to create a new AWS SimpleDB domain on Android 4.4

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-4.4-kitkat, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to test AWS SimpleDB connection on a Samsung Galaxy 4S (Android 4.4). This is my first time writing application for Android platform, and am still not quite used to how things work here. Below is what I bind to one of the button on the UI. The main purpose of the function should just be connecting to the AWS, and then create a domain for the data.

```
public void select_no1(View view) {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("MY_KEY_ID","MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");
    AmazonSimpleDBClient sdbClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credentials);
    sdbClient.setEndpoint("us-east-1");
    sdbClient.listDomains();
    CreateDomainRequest cdr = new CreateDomainRequest("test_from_and");
    sdbClient.createDomain(cdr);
}
```

It worked just fine at first, but the app crashes immediately once I added these two lines:

```
    CreateDomainRequest cdr = new CreateDomainRequest("test_from_and");
    sdbClient.createDomain(cdr);
```

Actually, doing this crashes the application, too.

```
    sdbClient.listDomains();
```

And below is the error I got from the LogCat. I am not sure what could be wrong here. :(

```
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3614)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4219)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17538)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3609)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    ... 11 more
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient.listDomains(Unknown Source)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient.listDomains(Unknown Source)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    at com.example.exitpoll.MainActivity.select_no1(MainActivity.java:85)
05-08 18:45:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(17016):    ... 14 more
05-08 18:45:56.653: I/Process(17016): Sending signal. PID: 17016 SIG: 9
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: @SimplePlan So... I am not supposed to connect to AWS on the main thread?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a network connection in UI thread. make it in separate thread

try this simple solution. you need to handle according to your functionality.

```
public void select_no1(View view) {
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
  public void run() {
   AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("MY_KEY_ID","MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");
    AmazonSimpleDBClient sdbClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credentials);
    sdbClient.setEndpoint("us-east-1");
    sdbClient.listDomains();
    CreateDomainRequest cdr = new CreateDomainRequest("test_from_and");
    sdbClient.createDomain(cdr);                                                
                                                }
                                            }).start();
}
```