# Exception RestAdapter Handler

Tags: java, android, exception, web, retrofit

I've an android app that's crashing because of an error that i dont understand...

```
            String TEST_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080";
            PersonSvcApi personService = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(TEST_URL).setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).build()
                    .create(PersonSvcApi.class);

            Person person = new Person();

            String id = "234";
            person.setAge("21");
            person.setName("Test");
            person.setId(id);
            boolean ok = personService.addPerson(person);
            Collection<Person> people = personService.getPersonList();
```

The error appears in the two final lines, it seems like i'm doing something wrong with the connection but i dont get it. I've the web server working, i've already tried using it and it works with a simple java code. When i do it with android i get this:

```
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548): retrofit.RetrofitError
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at $Proxy0.addPerson(Native Method)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.example.cloudapp.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:72)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.FieldBindingStrategy$1.matches(FieldBindingStrategy.java:28)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:78)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:378)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:619)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:605)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:558)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:538)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.toBody(GsonConverter.java:80)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at retrofit.RequestBuilder.setArguments(RequestBuilder.java:353)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:298)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  ... 14 more
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:371)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.google.gson.util.N.<clinit>(N.java:87)
        10-27 10:09:20.031: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  ... 25 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

When you see "Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException", this means you are trying to make a network call on the main (UI) thread. Network calls can take a very short or long time to execute, so you don't want to make the user wait (freezing UI/having the application not respond).

I am guessing that the network call you made with Retrofit was in onCreate or triggered by some event listener. You will want to make this call instead on a separate thread (Thread, AsyncTask).