# Android activity2(XMLParser) force close when click button(activity1) on device

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, forceclose, nsxmlparsererrordomain

On mainactivity.java i have a button to open NewActivity.java(XMLParser),
but when click button my app forc close error on device. How to fix?

**logcat:**

> 09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-06 23:58:08.746:E/AndroidRuntime(14755):java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.buttonclicktutorial/com.androidbegin.buttonclicktutorial.NewActivity}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>
> 09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 09-06 23:58:08.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400) 09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 09-06 23:58:08.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604) 09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-06 23:58:08.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14755): Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 09-06 23:58:08.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385) 09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   com.androidbegin.buttonclicktutorial.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:45)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   com.androidbegin.buttonclicktutorial.NewActivity.onCreate(NewActivity.java:42
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)   09-06
>   23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
>   09-06 23:58:08.746: E/AndroidRuntime(14755):  ... 11 more

**mainactivity.java**

```
package com.androidbegin.buttonclicktutorial;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

        // Capture button clicks
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

**NewActivity.java**

```
    package com.androidbegin.buttonclicktutorial;    
    import ir.adad.Adad;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class NewActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Adad.setTestMode(true);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, " " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);    
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    list_item.xml(second activity layout)
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Name Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#dc6800"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
        <!-- Description label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desciption"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <!-- Linear layout for cost and price Cost: Rs.100 -->

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Cost Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="" >
        </TextView>
        <!-- Price Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac" 
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="left">
        </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidbegin.buttonclicktutorial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

               </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NewActivity" >
        </activity> 

        <activity 
            android:label="Single Menu Item"
            android:name=".SingleMenuItemActivity" >
        </activity> 
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </manifest>
```

On mainactivity.java i have a button to open NewActivity.java(XMLParser),
but when click button my app forc close error on device. How to fix?

Comment: Are you seeing a stack trace or any information printed to the console? Please include that if so.

Comment: I add logcat...

Comment: I add logcat...

Comment: Google this: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
I add below code into NewActivity.java after setContentView(R.layout.main); and set android:minSdkVersion="9" on manifest thanx.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

}

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```