# How to fetch data from an URL in Android?

Tags: android, http

For the app I am making I need to get data (a CSV or JSON file) from a specific URL, but I can't get it to work. It seems that I have to make the request in another thread (NetworkOnMainThreadException) but I don't know how to do that. What is the correct way to make a request to a webpage and retrieve the data?

Comment: Do you have the URL to fetch data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an HTTP request with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it's a duplicate I am going to answear.
The best way to do this is to use asynchronous method:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        for (; count <= params[0]; count++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                publishProgress(count);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
              JSONObject response = getJSONObjectFromURL("your http link"); // calls method to get JSON object 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Task Completed.";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        txt.setText("Task Starting...");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        txt.setText("Running..."+ values[0]);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
```

And here is the class to get JSON from http and parse it. When calling the method pass in the url you wish to get the json object from.

```
 public static JSONObject getJSONObjectFromURL(String urlString) throws IOException, JSONException {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    urlConnection.connect();

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    char[] buffer = new char[1024];

    String jsonString = new String();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line+"\n");
    }
    br.close();

    jsonString = sb.toString();

    System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonString);
    urlConnection.disconnect();

    return new JSONObject(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: What is `char[] buffer = new char[1024];` for? It looks unused to me.

Comment: AsyncTasks are now deprecated in Android unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Use AsyncTask and put all your Network Actions into "doInBackground" and work with yout result-data in "onPostExecute".

for a example you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18827536/2377961